# Regular Expression - Get text between double curly brackets and avoid escaped curly brackets

Tags: regex, variables, autoit, between, curly-brackets

I have been working in an AutoIt program which is supposed to receive variables declared into a .ini file. Later those variables can can called using double curly brackets "{{}}" and single curly brackets "{}". Here is an example.

```
Variable is defined by user as: VAR1 = "C:\MyDir\"
When user calls {{VAR1}} it receives "C:\\MyDir\\"
When user calls {VAR1} it receives "C:\MyDir\"
```

Double curly brackets replaces "\" for "\\"; single curly brackets gives only the actual variable value.

The problems are:

1) User may use curly brackets in variable definition: 
{VAR1} = "C:\MyDir\" Or {{VAR1}} = "C:\MyDir\" ...

2) User may write a text using curly brackets and call a variable inside the text:

My sample text {{{VAR1}}} my sample text.

User calls {VAR1} variable using the second {{VAR1}} curly bracket and want the result to be displayed inside the third curly bracket.

User expects this: "My sample text {C:\MyDir} my sample text."

To avoid the potential problems of this curly brackets recurssion I would like to define a rule to use escaped curly brackets "{" when user wants to write a real curly bracket and a non-escaped curly bracket when user is calling a variable.

Based on the previous explanation, I need a regular expression capable of resolving the following example:

```
\{{{\{VAR1\}}}\}
```

The escaped curly brackets must be ignored and function should return \{VAR1\} as the variable name. In this case variable "real" name is "{VAR1}".

I hope you can help me.

Best regards,

Aeolis

Comment: I have build the following regular expression which seems to work **(?<!\\)\{(?<!\\)\{(.*)(?<!\\)\}(?<!\\)\}**. Can anyone comment this possible solution?

Comment: Acc. to regex101.com, this regex is not correct as "lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed". This fixed `(?<!\\)\{(?<!\\)\{(.*)(?<!\\)\}(?<!\\)\}` pattern matches `{{\{VAR1\}}}`, as it is looking for 2 `{`s not preceded with "\", then for any number of any characters but newline, and then 2 `}`s with no "\" in front. So, basically, it is `(?<!\\)\{{2}(.*)(?<!\\)\}{2}` matching `{{\{VAR1\}}}`. Perhaps, you need `\\\{(?<!\\)\{{2}(.*)(?<!\\)\}{2}\\\}` matching the entire `\{{{\{VAR1\}}}\}` with a `\{VAR1\}` subgroup? See https://regex101.com/r/lP5iW8/1.

Comment: Autoit has an Execute() function which may may be a better approach then creating a programming language in Autoit :) just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you **stribizhev** for your correction and for the link to "regex101.com" (very good source for help). Yes, one solution to my problem is the pattern: `(?<!\\)\{(?<!\\)\{(.*)(?<!\\)\}(?<!\\)\}`

Thank you all!

Best regards,

Aeolis